# Flattening a relation with an array to emit one row per array entry

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, set-returning-functions, lateral

Given a table defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE test_values(name TEXT, values INTEGER[]);
```

...and the following values:

```
| name  | values  |
+-------+---------+
| hello | {1,2,3} |
| world | {4,5,6} |
```

I'm trying to find a query which will return:

```
| name  | value |
+-------+-------+
| hello | 1     |
| hello | 2     |
| hello | 3     |
| world | 4     |
| world | 5     |
| world | 6     |
```

I've reviewed [the upstream documentation on accessing arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING), and tried to think about what a solution using [the `unnest()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) would look like, but have been coming up empty.

An ideal solution would be easy to use even in cases where there were a significant number of columns other than the array being expanded and no primary key. Handling a case with more than one array is not important.

Comment: Doesn't `select name, unnest(values) "value" from test_values;` work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

We can put the set-returning function [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) into the `SELECT` list [like Raphaël suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997738/939860). This used to exhibit corner case problems before Postgres 10. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Since Postgres 9.3 we can also use a [**`LATERAL`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join for this. It is the cleaner, standard-compliant way to put set-returning functions into the `FROM` list, not into the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT name, value
FROM   tbl, unnest(values) value;  -- implicit CROSS JOIN LATERAL
```

One subtle difference: this drops rows with empty / NULL `values` from the result since `unnest()` returns *no row*, while the same is converted to a NULL value in the `FROM` list and returned anyway. The 100 % equivalent query is:

```
SELECT t.name, v.value
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN unnest(t.values) v(value) ON true;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. A quick question. What is the `v(value)` on the last query. I understood that `v` is the alias, but I have never seen this notation in the past. Many thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 14):

Well, you give the data, the doc, so... let's mix it ;)

```
select 
 name, 
 unnest(values) as value 
from test_values
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d4292/2)

Comment: Unfamiliar with the semantics of selecting a tuple with a sequence as one of its elements, I can plead. I'll accept this when the timer runs out.