# Generate one additional row per array element

Tags: sql, postgresql, unnest, set-returning-functions

Using PostgreSQL 9.6, I'm trying to insert rows into a table `map`, generated from another table `tbl`.

`tbl`

| name | in1 | in2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 |  |
| b | 2 | {3} |
| c | 4 | {5,6} |
| d | 7 | {8,9,10} |

Should result in this:

`map`

| name | out1 | out2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |
| c | 4 | 4 |
| c | 4 | 5 |
| c | 4 | 6 |
| d | 7 | 7 |
| d | 7 | 8 |
| d | 7 | 9 |
| d | 7 | 10 |

`in1` and each value in the array `in2` should get entries for user `name`. I can't figure out how best to iterate through the array, whether it's a subselect, or a built-in operator.

So far I have:

```sql
INSERT INTO map(name, out1, out2)
SELECT (name, in1, in1)
FROM
    tbl;

UPDATE map
SET out2 = 
    (loop possibly of in2?)
FROM
    tbl t
WHERE
     name = t.name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```sql
INSERT INTO map (name, out1, out2)
SELECT pname, in1, unnest(in1 || in2)
FROM   tbl
```

Assuming this table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  pname text PRIMARY KEY
, in1   integer NOT NULL
, in2   integer[]  --  can be NULL?
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5pVRo2Ah)

Notably, `in2` is an integer array (`integer[]`). Else, cast with `in2::int[]` - you have valid array literals on display.

About the element-to-array concatenation in `in1 || in2`, see:

- [How can the concatenatation of a text and a NULL value return a non-null result?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/233522/3684)

`in1` and `in2` can be `NULL`, but consider corner cases demonstrated in my fiddle. You may want to move `unnest()` to a `LATERAL` subquery to steer corner cases. See:

- [Flattening a relation with an array to emit one row per array entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997662/flattening-a-relation-with-an-array-to-emit-one-row-per-array-entry/32001490#32001490)

Careful with multiple set-returning functions like `unnest()` in the `SELECT` list, especially before Postgres 10. (Not an issue with just one.) See:

- [Split column into multiple rows in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419993/split-column-into-multiple-rows-in-postgres/29420035#29420035)
- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Comment: should have mentioned in1 is int NOT NULL, and in2 is int[] (can be NULL). Returning an error that in1 is of type integer but  expression is of type character varying (name of of type varchar, for the record)

Comment: @DanielPowley: *"`in1` is `int NOT NULL`, and `in2` is `int[]`"*  - then there is no `varchar` involved, and the error makes no sense. Should just work, as demonstrated in the fiddle (in pg 15 and pg 9.6 alike).

Comment: Tried again. This worked, looks like my ordering was wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into map (name, out1, out2)
select * from (
select name, int1, unnest(int2) int2 from tbl
union all
select name, int1, int1 from tbl) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which format your array is stored, but here's one method that works if it's a TEXT column. Using the split-to-table function combined with replace, then casting that to integer.

```
select *
from (
    select pname, in1 as out1, in1 as out2
    from tbl
    union
    select pname, in1 as out1,  
    nullif(regexp_replace(regexp_split_to_table(in2, ','), '\D', '','g'), '')::integer
    from tbl
  )z
where out2 is not null
order by 1,2
```

Output:

| pname | out1 | out2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 3 |
| c | 4 | 4 |
| c | 4 | 5 |
| c | 4 | 6 |
| d | 7 | 7 |
| d | 7 | 8 |
| d | 7 | 9 |
| d | 7 | 10 |

Fiddle [found here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gV7GV6CAaq92LC4wQikzcF/1). Just wrap with an update statement.